# Where are all the secrets in Shadow Warrior (2013)?

Tags: shadow-warrior

I've just started playing the new Shadow Warrior game and I've noticed that after each level there is a statistics page where I can see how many secrets I've managed to find.

Just out of curiosity: is there a complete list of all the secrets which can be found in this game? I tried google but I only get hits for the old Shadow Warrior game.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use the following link to find the (all) the secrets.

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?feature=c4-feed-u&list=PLozlkF2rE5a92g5-HeXGHcoC_rTYiCEjX

The next link is a guide that has (most) but not all of them.
Edit: Switched the link to the original Creator.

http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=181585906

Comment: It is a remake indeed but it has **completely different** levels.

Comment: The videos should have them all.

Comment: This is the best guide I have found. http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=181585906 Do NOT use the levelupguides one as they stole everything from the one I posted.

Comment: @AdamArold: My best guess, some people are strict about providing information, not just links.